# How to SignIn with google on Parse Server

Tags: flutter, google-signin, parse-server

I'm developing an application with Flutter and Parse Server and I want to register Users from google account.

I have tried:

```
static Future<void> loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {

      final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']);
      final account = await _googleSignIn.signIn(); // I figure out that the real error is here;

      final authentication = await account.authentication;
      
      final googleAuth = google(_googleSignIn.currentUser.id, authentication.accessToken, authentication.idToken);
      final response = await ParseUser.loginWith('google', googleAuth);
          
      if (response.success) {
        print(response);
        //currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser(customUserObject: User.clone());
        //Get.offNamed('/oauth');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      AlertUtils.showErrorDialog(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

but here I faced that error:

> plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed,
> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Comment: have you enabled google sign in in firebase ?

Comment: I don't want to use Firebase Authentification just want to connect directly to google Api to get UserName / Email / ...

Comment: @stacjaa Did you find any success implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without registering on Firebase. The official [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) says so.

Comment: Ok but in documentation: 'You don't need to include the google-services.json file in your app' If I don't need to include google.json how I can relate my app with firebase just for using User data

Comment: You will need to use Google Cloud OAuth API.